# Typescript interface for Laravel pagination

Tags: laravel

As you know Eloquent ORM returns a paginator with many different values, variable names and other information are not known by Typescript on the front-end, however.

Does anything know of any Type or Interface for the Laravel paginator?

Comment: [The JSON schema for Eloquent's pagination object is semi-documented online](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#pagination), is there a reason you can't define your own `interface` for it yourself?

Comment: Where is the API documentation of the endpoint you are consuming? If you give us the link we can explain how you can create types from the OpenAPI documentation provided by your backend.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I could. Am I shameful for not doing it? It's a lot of typing and I might get a type wrong. I just think its weird a popular part of Laravel has no Typescript support. I suppose it depends on the front-end someone is using.

Comment: @EricMORAND I'm just passing MyClassName::query()->paginate() to my Vue front-end. So the API end-point is just web.php, right? I suppose I should just write the interfaces myself, but I feel like a bit of a loser doing so because, why hasn't anyone else done it?

Comment: @JollyBoy actually a lot of people - most of us even - do exactly that: write the interfaces themselves. This is in my opinion totally mandatory. :) But there are also some tools that are able to generate the types for you based on OpenAPI documents - openapi-typescript for example - but you need an OpenAPI document to begin with which it seems you don't have. So, write your own interfaces. That's the way to go.